# UITableViewDelegate´s tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: called for non-existing cells?

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I see calls to `UITableViewDelegate`´s `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` where `indexPath.row` is larger than the value that was previously returned from `UITableViewDataSource`s `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` for the same section.

For instance, if the number of rows in section 0 is 1, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` may be called with `{ section = 0, row = 1}`.

Is this a feature or a bug (in my code or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has by now disappeared. I think it may have been related to a race condition with a background thread that updated a table's data source.